# JavaScript sort / shuffle while maintain to a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a use case something like this.

1. I have a questions base.
2. Each question belongs to a one question type.
3. I need to display a question paper (Questions shuffle) where questions come from one type after other.

```js
const question_types = [
{id:1, type:"science"},
{id:2, type:"history"},
{id:3, type:"current affairs"},
{id:4, type:"maths"}
]

const questions = [
{id:1,question:"World War I began in which year?",type:2},
{id:2,question:"Adolf Hitler was born in which country?",type:2},
{id:3,question:"Which general famously stated 'I shall return'?",type:2},
{id:4,question:"The Magna Carta was published by the King of which country? ",type:2},

{id:5,question:"10 + 12? ",type:4},
{id:6,question:"10 - 12? ",type:4},
{id:7,question:"10 + 192? ",type:4},

{id:8,question:"Who is the prime minister of Canada?",type:3},
{id:9,question:"Who is the prime minister of India?",type:3},
{id:10,question:"Who is the prime minister of UK?",type:3},
{id:11,question:"Who is the prime minister of Sri lanka?",type:3},
{id:12,question:"Who is the president of USA?",type:3},
{id:13,question:"Who is the president of France?",type:3},

{id:14,question:"Name the four states in which matter exists.?",type:1},

]
```

This is a sample data set.
Here I have

- Science - 1 question,
- Current affairs - 6 questions,
- Maths - 3 questions,
- History - 4 questions

I would except sorting the question in this pattern

Science, history, current affairs, maths, history, current affairs, maths, history, current affairs, maths, history, current affairs,
current affairs, current affairs

How could I achieve this using JavaScript?
And if you ask what I have done upto now?

I iterate in `forEach` and extract type `ids` first.
Then I use `filter` to filter it by type and lost.

Comment: What number of max questions you want?

Comment: All the questions in the database should come to the paper no max questions.

Comment: _"I would except sorting the question in this pattern"_ Why is that pattern expected?

Comment: @guest271314 pattern means this base has S -1, C- 6, M-3, H-4 questions. Since this system has 1 science question and 4 types of questions that science question should appear in first set of 4 questions. S, C, M, H like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below. Loop over main `questions` array and fetch one by one question as your required sequence and push into `sortedQuestions` array.

```js
const question_types = [
  {id:1, type:"science"},
  {id:2, type:"history"},
  {id:3, type:"current affairs"},
  {id:4, type:"maths"}
];

const questions = [
  {id:1,question:"World War I began in which year?",type:2},
  {id:2,question:"Adolf Hitler was born in which country?",type:2},
  {id:3,question:"Which general famously stated 'I shall return'?",type:2},
  {id:4,question:"The Magna Carta was published by the King of which country? ",type:2},

  {id:5,question:"10 + 12? ",type:4},
  {id:6,question:"10 - 12? ",type:4},
  {id:7,question:"10 + 192? ",type:4},

  {id:8,question:"Who is the prime minister of Canada?",type:3},
  {id:9,question:"Who is the prime minister of India?",type:3},
  {id:10,question:"Who is the prime minister of UK?",type:3},
  {id:11,question:"Who is the prime minister of Sri lanka?",type:3},
  {id:12,question:"Who is the president of USA?",type:3},
  {id:13,question:"Who is the president of France?",type:3},

  {id:14,question:"Name the four states in which matter exists.?",type:1},
];

const sequence = ["science", "history", "current affairs", "maths"];
let sequenceTypes = sequence.map(x => question_types.filter(y => y.type == x)[0]);
let sortedQuestions = [];
let index = 0;

while(questions.length > 0) {
  var i = questions.findIndex(x => x.type == sequenceTypes[index].id);
  if (i != -1) {
    sortedQuestions.push(questions.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
  index = (index + 1) % sequenceTypes.length;
}

console.log(sortedQuestions);
```

Comment: Please don't answer with only code, describe how you're solving the problem

Comment: @Matsemann It was small logic and I thought it would be self explanatory. I have edited my answer. Though I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const question_types = [
{id:1, type:"science"},   // -> 1
{id:2, type:"history"},   // -> 2
{id:3, type:"current affairs"}, // -> 3
{id:4, type:"maths"}   // -> 4
];

const questions = [
{id:1,question:"World War I began in which year?",type:2},
{id:2,question:"Adolf Hitler was born in which country?",type:2},
{id:3,question:"Which general famously stated 'I shall return'?",type:2},
{id:4,question:"The Magna Carta was published by the King of which country? ",type:2},

{id:5,question:"10 + 12? ",type:4},
{id:6,question:"10 - 12? ",type:4},
{id:7,question:"10 + 192? ",type:4},

{id:8,question:"Who is the prime minister of Canada?",type:3},
{id:9,question:"Who is the prime minister of India?",type:3},
{id:10,question:"Who is the prime minister of UK?",type:3},
{id:11,question:"Who is the prime minister of Sri lanka?",type:3},
{id:12,question:"Who is the president of USA?",type:3},
{id:13,question:"Who is the president of France?",type:3},

{id:14,question:"Name the four states in which matter exists.?",type:1}
];

var ques = questions;
var dynamicappendVal = [];


while(0 < ques.length) {
 for(let i=0;i<question_types.length;i++) {
   for(let j=0;j<ques.length;j++) {
  if(question_types[i].id == ques[j].type) {
   dynamicappendVal.push(ques[j]);
   ques.splice(ques.indexOf(ques[j]),1);
   break;
  }
   }
 }
}
console.log(dynamicappendVal);
```

Comment: Hi,  this is simple logic
First const can't changeable, so assign to new variable, then creating empty array to store & print values.    

Using while loop for question length > 0, then using two for loops 1st one question type and 2nd questions then **question type id** is equal to **question id** then push and remove the selected value.
     
Finally print the array

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with little explanation

```
let pattern = "science, history, current affairs, maths, history, current affairs, maths ,history, current affairs, maths,history, current affairs, current affairs,current affairs"
//split pattern string
pattern = pattern.split(',').map(type=>type.trim());
//convert eact item in array to its type number id in question_types
pattern = pattern.map(type => (question_types.find(typeItem => typeItem.type === type).id))

function sortQuestions(arr, pattern){
    let resultArr = [];  //array to be returned
    for(let type of pattern){
        //find index of question of desired type
        let questionNo = arr.findIndex(question => question.type === type);
        //push into the resultArr
        resultArr.push(arr[questionNo]);
        //remove it from main array so that it wouldn't repeat
        arr.splice(questionNo,1);
    }
    return resultArr;
}
```